# POST request for paginating, sorting results

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, http-method

I am currently doing a `GET` request that uses a bunch of methods that I wrote to query the database and display them. This works great, but I want to make it a `POST` request method so that the methods do not have to depend on `req.query`, deal with a json body instead of a string of URL params which would would facilitate the url string not to have anything else except the endpoints and make it as dynamic as possible. Any idea how to do this?

This is my controller method:

```
exports.getBooks = async (req, res, next) => {

    const bookList = new BookList(Book.find(), req.query)
        .filter()
        .sort()
        .paginate();

    const books = await bookList.query;
    
    res.status(200)
        .json({
            books,
        });
};
```

This is the BookList class that has all the methods:

```
class BookList {
    constructor(query, queryString) {
        this.query = query;
        this.queryString = queryString;
    }

    filter() {
        const queryObj = { ...this.queryString };
        const excludedFields = ['page', 'sort', 'limit', 'fields'];
        excludedFields.forEach(el => delete queryObj[el]);

        let queryStr = JSON.stringify(queryObj);

        this.query = this.query.find(JSON.parse(queryStr));

        return this;
    }

    sort() {
        if (this.queryString.sort) {
            const sortBy = this.queryString.sort.split(',').join(' ');
            this.query = this.query.sort(sortBy);
        } else {
            this.query = this.query.sort('-createdAt');
        }

        return this;
    }

    paginate() {
        const page = Number(this.queryString.page) || 1;
        const limit = Number(this.queryString.limit) || 100;
        const skip = (page - 1) * limit;

        this.query = this.query.skip(skip).limit(limit);

        return this;
    }
}
module.exports = BookList;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what worked for me:

```
exports.getBooks = async (req, res, next) => {
    let bookBody = req.body
    const bookList = new BookList(Book.find(), req.query)
        .filter(bookBody, req)
        .sort()
        .paginate();

    const books = await bookList.query;
    
    res.status(200)
        .json({
            books,
        });
};

filter(bookBody, req) {
        const filterBooks = bookBody.filter
        const bookId = req.params.bookId

        let requiredFilter
        if (filterBooks) {
            requiredFilter = {bookStatus: filterBooks.bookStatus, bookId};
        } else {
            requiredFilter = { bookId}
        }
        this.query = this.query.find(requiredFilter)

        return this;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to convert it to POST with json body then you will use something like below

```js
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')

// parse application/json
app.use(bodyParser.json())


exports.getBooks = async (req, res, next) => {

    const bookList = new BookList(Book.find(), req.body)
        .filter()
        .sort()
        .paginate();

    const allReports = await bookList.query;
    
    res.status(200)
        .json({
            books,
        });
};
```

In this I assumed that parameters name will still be the same. Also the two lines for json parser needs to be in the file where you initialise the express server

Comment: I am not trying to convert the data to JSON, rather trying to use the json body vs using the req.query object coming from the url

Comment: I still didn't understand what you want?

Comment: @TarunLalwani maybe you add a sample ajax post request ... haha ...

Answer (score 0):

When using an asynchronous javascript XML (AJAX) request to send and receive back data from the server, it is possible to specify either a "POST" or a "GET" request.  Any number of items may be sent or received via a single such request, as is shown in the sample script below.  In your case, you would tailor it to have the script send your JSON data.

```
function AJAXroutine(val1,val2) { /* NAME IT WHATEVER YOU LIKE */
    var formAction=document.getElementById("MyForm").getAttribute('action');

    function Q(){
        var K=new XMLHttpRequest();
        var frm=new FormData();

        /* CAN HAVE ANY NUMBER OF VALUES SENT BACK TO SERVER */
        frm.append('V1',val1);
        frm.append('V2',val2);
        frm.append('V3',document.getElementById('another_elmt').value);
        frm.append('V4',document.getElementById('another_one').value);

        K.onreadystatechange=function(){
            if(this.readyState==4&&this.status==200){

                /* IF MULTIPLE VALUES ARE RETURNED */
                var data=this.responseText.split("|");
                document.getElementById('my_elmt').innerHTML=data[0];
                document.getElementById('my_text').value=data[1];
                /* ETC. */

                /* IF JUST ONE VALUE IS RETURNED */
                document.getElementById('my_elmt').value=this.responseText;
            };
        };
        /* CAN OPTIONALLY CHANGE 'POST' TO 'GET' */
        K.open('post',formAction); 
        K.send(frm)
    }
    Q();
}
```

This is a very basic template for an AJAX request and can be easily adapted to suit one's individual requirements.